# Is there a deterministic way to have a platform independent check of Java 3D rendering capabilities?

Tags: java-3d

We have have an application using the java 3D API.
I know that java 3D will try to use whichever 3D rendering engine is available on the machine.

1. Is there an API that will detect whether a client machine is capable of using the entire java 3D API ?

Example: recently we got the stacktrace below from a client using A Windows 8 tablet with Java Web Start 10.25.2.16, Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b16 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM.

```
Exception occurred in RenderingErrorListener:java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
```

We implemented javax.media.j3d.RenderingError and got the message below:

> OFF_SCREEN_BUFFER_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D off-screen buffer
>   graphicsDevice = Win32GraphicsDevice[screen=0]

- Is there a way to get more details about the error ?
- Is there any way to debug the rendering engine discovery/selection ?

Answer (score 1):

The WebStart version in Java 7u25 stores the sun.awt.AppContext no longer on the system thread group. It stores the AppContext on the main thread.

Therefore threads belonging to a thread group the main thread group is not a parent or grandparent of has no AppContext.

see also: [NullPointerException in invokeLater while running through Java Webstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275259/nullpointerexception-in-invokelater-while-running-through-java-webstart)