# applet fileopen dialog npe

Tags: java, applet

I am getting this stack trace in applet code that worked in jre6.0.33+ but fail with this in 7.025.  Can anyone help me understand why and correct?

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.revalidate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.resizeAndRepaint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sorterChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RowSorter.fireRowSorterChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RowSorter.fireRowSorterChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sort(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane$DetailsTableRowSorter.access$1601(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane$DetailsTableRowSorter$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.FilePane$DetailsTableRowSorter$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - please *read* the helpful tag pop-ups.  If you had, you might have realized this has nothing to do with the [tag:openfiledialog] tag. -1 to remind you to do so in future.

Comment: I have this problem too. It is a bug from Sun but will be fixed in JDK8

Comment: Actually, it seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275259/nullpointerexception-in-invokelater-while-running-through-java-webstart)

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa
Yes, I should have refrained and read.  The problem is with sorting the dialog box.  I accept my down merit punishment.  I hope I can still post naive though they be.  Please note this is not sarcastic, even with that statement just under pressure.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same, and it is apparently an "incarnation" of [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8019274), according to [this forum post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/swing-dev/2014-February/003295.html). It seems to be fixed, but only in a JDK8 version. OTOH, it seems there is an "Apple patch" that fixed this in (presumably) JDK 7 (but only for Apple users).