# Applet does not run and crashes 7u55 plugin in chrome, Firefox and IE work fine

Tags: java, google-chrome, crash, applet, freeze

My applet in the webpage does not open and the Java plugin becomes unresponsive and chrome freezes out. 
I am new to Java Web Services. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Java Plug-in 10.55.2.14
Using JRE version 1.7.0_55-b14 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = 
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@15b758
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.windowsSettingChange(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@7544a6
security: Expected Main URL: http://soemething/applet.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://soemething/applet.jar
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1397750579401
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1397750579477 (we have 1397750579401)
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
network: Cache entry found [url: http://soemething/applet.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://soemething/applet.jar
cache: Resource http://soemething/applet.jar has expired.
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same NPE stack trace with JRE version 1.8.0_05-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, running a Java Webstart application.

Comment: Same exception stack in 7u55 as you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a multitude of known bugs regarding `NullPointerException` when calling `EventQueue.invokeLater()` after 7u25. Some of them are:

- [8017776](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017776), which was fixed in 8 and [backported](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8020571) to 7u60 (b01).
- [8019274](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8019274). Attempted fixes include [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275259/nullpointerexception-in-invokelater-while-running-through-java-webstart#19054146).

The fix for 8019274 might help you if the fix for 8017776 did not.

Comment: 7u60 (nightly) still does not work. It seems your links points to other issues.

Comment: Looks like this exception had nothing to do with the crash .. Applet crash is still not known . Fixed it by replacing current "embed" tag with "applet" tag !