# Web starter application throws JNLPException after update of JRE, Java 7u65

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Our customers have reported an issue that with high probability is caused by an JRE update, closer determined `JRE 7 update 65 (JRE 7u65)`. I was able to recreate this, the exception message I get is very unhelpful, looks like:

```
JNLPException[category: Launch File Error : Exception: null : LaunchDesc:
```

In Java Console output I see this:

```
Java Web Start 10.65.2.20    
Using JRE version 1.7.0_65-b20 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM    
#### Java Web Start Error:    
#### Could not find main-class se.linkon.sabine.clients.sabineclient.invoker.NBRunWrapper in .....
```

Do you have any clue what is wrong? Can this be a bug in JRE 7u65?

I have tested the application with `JRE 7u55` and with this configuration the application works smooth. I have tested on a **Windows 7** machine.

Best Regards

Comment: So with JRE 7u60 or any other JDK it is working?

Comment: I tested with JRE 7u60, it's working, but I had 2 crashes on 3 attempts, the Java-process freezed the first two attempts. I tested also with JRE 8u5 and JRE 8u11. When I run with the JRE 8u5 the Java-process dies abruptly, without exceptions or other strange messages in javaws.log or javaws.trace. With JRE 8u11 I get the same behavior as JRE 7u65.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your jnlp / jar file. Did you run janela? https://drive.google.com/?tab=co&authuser=0#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0

Comment: Thanks @Lonzak, It's my first time I use Janela, I got some hints of Janela, my first jar-tag in the JNLP-chain was not that containing the main-class, seems that JRE 7u55 and JRE 7u60 are more permissive, organize classpath in a different way maybe?

Comment: After adding the right jar-tag before existing, with attribute 'main' to true, it's working with 7u65, but with JRE 8u11 now I got another behavior, the same as when I tested with JRE 8, JRE 8u5, the Java-process abruptly die after:

    WARNING [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: AppContext group java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=javawsApplicationThreadGroup,maxpri=10] differs from originally used java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]

Comment: For that we need more source code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically I have a heavy client build on NetBeans Platform and we use Web Start to distribute it to our customers, this application has been in use about 2 years now, without issues. First this week after the update 7u65 we noticed that some big changes has been done in processing part of Web Start. So I'm trying to understand, what have been changed and why the application doesn't work anymore, just now in JRE 8. The application's JNLP-chain is autogenerate with Maven, in Janela Report I can see that under the hood, it's generated 60 extensions (JNLP-files).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the exact same problem moving from 1.7.0_60 to 1.7.0_67.

The solution in my case was that the main="true" attribute in the jnlp file was on the wrong jar.  I verified that this didn't matter under 1.7.0_60 or earlier.

However, nowhere in the _65 or _67 release notes does it mention this.  I suspect it's related to work for the -Entry-Point manifest attribute that's mentioned in the 1.8 stream release notes, but only Oracle could answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more details it is difficult to tell. There had been problems in that area  [NullPointerException in invokeLater while running through Java Webstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275259/nullpointerexception-in-invokelater-while-running-through-java-webstart) however its just taking stabs in the dark...